# Отправка параметров на сервер

Tags: android, webview

Мне нужно взять и послать на сервер эти параметры `(http_X_wap_Profile,Http_Referer, IMEI, MSISDN)`. Как мне это сделать? Я использую 'WebView' как браузер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ряд параметров можно передавать заполняя заголовки путем передачи дополнительных параметров в loadUrl:

```
Map<String, String> extra = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
   put("Referer", "http://hashcode.ru");
}};

webview.loadUrl("http://sezn.ru", extra);
```

Comment: Я сначала не знал как делать у меня был Апи 7,потом уже пришлось перейти на 8 из за этого метода.